# Changing properties of QWidget using python init function with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a form created with the Drag and Drop Designer in QGIS, and it contains a Relation Reference widget.

Is there any way to change the available XML configuration from within a python init function for the QGIS form?

```
<edittype widgetv2type="RelationReference" name="tree_uid">
      <widgetv2config OrderByValue="0" fieldEditable="1" AllowAddFeatures="1" ShowForm="1" Relation="test20160803125723549_tree_uid_taxa_tree_detail20160812111449449_UKEY" ReadOnly="1" constraint="" MapIdentification="0" labelOnTop="1" constraintDescription="" notNull="0" AllowNULL="0"/>
```